Не скачивается файл с помощью selenium на сервере
Использую VPS на ос ubuntu
Задача: запустить скрипт в фоновом режиме
При переходе по ссылке сразу скачивается csv файл.
Когда запускаю скрипт локально, все работает, аутентификация не требуется.
В коде настроила папку для загрузок, в которой находится сам скрипт, но при запуске на сервере всегда вылезает ошибка, что файл или дирректория не найдены.
Потому что сам файл, видимо, не может скачаться и при запуске  команды
find / -name 'downloaddatapartial.csv'

ничего не выводится.  Значит нигде в другом месте его нет
Не могу понять, почему не может скачаться сам файл.
Вот код
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
            "download.default_directory": "/home/hub_indicators/",
            "download.prompt_for_download": False,
            "profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads": 2,
            "download.directory_upgrade": True,
            "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
options.set_capability("good:loggingPrefs", {"performance": "ALL"})
service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
browser.close()
df = pd.read_csv("/home/hub_indicators/downloaddatapartial.csv") (в этой строке возникает ошибка)


which - это для прог, а не для файлов. Я не шарю в питоне и селениуме, но в твоём коде не увидел как ты скачиваешь csv. Кстати, чем не устроил wget/curl/aria2c? Они отлично справляются с закачкой. Хотя я уверен, в питоне тоже есть какой-нить fetch.

@donRumata, когда браузер открывает ссылку, там сразу происходит скачивание файла (в строке browser.get(url))

@donRumata, другие методы для скачивания не работают. я же говорю, если локально запускать, файл скачивается.  у этого сайта видимо стоят различные блокировки, и пока что я только с помощью ыelenium могу выкачать данные

Дёрнул прогами, которые сам посоветовал. wget говорит Username/Password Authentication Failed., curl говорит <p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p>. Ты логин/пасс от сайта передавать не пробовала?

у меня нет там личного кабинета, все данные можно получить без регистрации. как я писала выше, локально все работает, я не передаю логин и пароль

@donRumata, если бы ошибка была в отсутствии аутентификации, то selenium выдал бы предупреждение так же, как и wget

Я вижу, что через браузер качается ок. Но вероятно для автоматических загрузчиков надо завести учётку и передавать её во время скачивания. Это не проверял, просто предположение.

видимо, я поняла в чем дело. этот сайт просит решить капчу, когда какой-то новый ip используется. решить ее можно только в окне самого браузера, капча называется DataDome. поскольку я запускаю в фоновом режиме, то увидеть я этого не могу. значит надо думать над тем, как автоматически решать капчу.

Через заведение учётки таки подумай.

@это не помогло. даже для того, чтобы ввести логин и пароль сайт требует решить капчу

https://stackoverflow.com/q/51970543, https://pypi.org/project/marketwatch/ походу не ты первая, кто хочет обращаться к сайту не руками. И походу всё плохо.
